# Firestore security rules based on role

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I've written those Firestore security rules to allow only users who are approved, work with data:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /bikes/{document} {

     function getRole(role) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isApproved
      }

      allow read: if getRole() == true;
      allow write: if getRole() == true;

    }
  }
}
```

But getting this error

> core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
>       at new FirestoreError (index.cjs.js:346)

Whats wrong?

Extra code:

1) [Firestore record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDiaH.png)

1) Angular code

```
getUserData() {
    this.afAuthState.authState.subscribe(user => {
      console.log(user)
      console.log("user uid")
      console.log(user.uid)
      if (user) {
          this.dao.getEmployeeByUID(user.uid).subscribe( res => {
            if (res) {
              console.log(res)
              this.employee = res
              this.role = this.employee.role
            }
            else console.log("please ask the admin for confirmation")
          })
        }
        else console.log("please login")
      })
  }
```

**When I apply rules, I couldnt fetch this (getEmployeeByUID) data. when there are no rules - its fine**

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal standalone code with which you trigger this error. It would also be good to see the document where the role for the user is defined. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is looking for matches under a collection called `docs`, but you have no such collection.  It seems your rule should be placed on the collection called `employees`.

Comment: its fine, I use a "bikes" collection

Comment: All you did was update your rule to use the "bikes" collection instead of "docs".  Is this the collection that's queried when you call `getEmployeeByUID`?  (It's impossible to tell - you should show the exact query being performed.)

Comment: getEmployeeByUID(uid) {
    return this.afs.doc(this.fsCollectionName+'/'+uid).valueChanges();
  } this one? its a simple query. fsCollectionName = "employees";

Comment: And what is `fsCollectionName`?  Exactly what collection are you really querying here?

Comment: its a String reference to firestore collection

Comment: And exactly what collection are you really querying here?

Comment: i am fetching Bikes. But condition is from Employees

Comment: and this error appears without fetching data (using a data @Service) from Bikes. It appears on the index page, before i go to grab data from Bikes